# Encode array contents with base64

Tags: javascript

I want to encode my array contents with base64 if possible in javascript (and then decode later).

Example:

```
var array = ["stack", "overflow"]
// base64.encode(array)
```

Comment: a simple google search would have yielded this exact page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Base64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code:

```
var array = ["stack", "overflow"]

array.map(btoa);
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the well-known function [`btoa`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa), you'll first have to convert your array to string, in such a way that you can reverse the operation. JSON would be the string format to go for.

So to encode do:

```
base64 = btoa(JSON.stringify(array))
```

To decode do:

```
JSON.parse(atob(base64))
```